# Installing python packages in jupyterhub from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I try to build a shared code platform using jupyterhub for our work group. I want all users to have some packages preinstalled in their jupyterhub environment when starting a new server. I use this Dockerfile (and a `jupyterhub_config.py` and `docker-compose.yaml`):

```
FROM jupyterhub/jupyterhub:latest

RUN pip install --no-cache \
    oauthenticator \
    dockerspawner \
    jupyterhub-nativeauthenticator

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install vim

COPY requirements.txt /home/jovyan/work/requirements.txt
COPY jupyterhub_config.py /srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py
RUN pip install -r /home/jovyan/work/requirements.txt
```

However all the packages in install in the last line are only being installed in the Container VM and are not accessable from the notebooks.
E.g. `RUN pip install torch` in the Dockerfile and then using `import torch` in the notebook does not work.
How can I set up the Jupyterhub to have the requirements.txt installed when starting up?

Is the Dockerfile the right address or can I do this in the jupyterhub_config.py or somewhere else?